# .tex files set to open with TeX.mdimporter (1.3)

Tags: mac, texshop, mactex

I created a second account on my Mac in an attempt to workaround a fuzzy display issues I am having with TeXShop. When I select "Get Info" on a .tex file it seems to be set to open with *TeX.mdimporter*:

[image]

This *seems* like a very easy fix. I change the default application to *TeXShop* and select "Change All...":

[image]

and select "Continue":

[image]

However, after these steps I return to Finder and "Get Info" still shows that it is set to open with *TeX.mdimporter*?

Luckily, when I double click, the file correctly opens with TeXShop so not sure what Finder seems to think it should open with some other app.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this minor annoyance?

### Info

- OS: macOS Mojave V10.14.6
- TeXShop 4.31
- The files between the two accounts are synched using Dropbox (in case that has something to do with it).

Comment: What version of TeXShop are you using? Do you happen to have a copy of TeX.mdimporter in `~/Library/Spotlight? If so, remove it. Finally, you may have to rebuild the LaunchServices database: run the command `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` (NOTE: all of that should be on one line!) in Terminal.app. Hopefully that will clear up your problem.

Comment: It is the latest version TeXShop v4.31. I do _not_ seem to have a `~/Library/Spotlight` folder.  Running the given command did indeed clear up the problem. Please post that as an answer. Thanks Herb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to rebuild the LaunchServices database: run the command `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` (NOTE: all of that should be on one line!) in Terminal.app. Hopefully that will clear up your problem.